# Average of maximum

Tags: sql

I am new to sql and tried to find similar topic, but with no success.
If someone could help, I will be very grateful:-)

Here is a tiny part of big code, which is based on Group by 1 column 'CustomerID' (and I do not need more!).
I need to calculate Maximum of [Field] per each year and afterwards arrive at average of those MAX values.

```
SELECT
t0.[CustomerID]
,MAX(t0.[CustomerName]) as 'CustomerName'
,SUM(CASE WHEN t0.[Year] = 2021 then t0.[SalesValue_USD] END) as 'Sales_USD_2021'
,SUM(t0.[SalesValue_USD]) as 'Sales_USD_total'
,AVG(MAX(t0.[Field]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Year])) as 'Field_avr'

From market t0
Where [Year] in (2019,2020,2021)
Group by t0.[CustomerID]
```

Comment: Can your provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: Why are you using `MAX()` as a window function rather than just a straight aggregate?  And how does `Year` play into the aggregation?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two steps

```
SELECT [CustomerID],
    MAX('CustomerName') as 'CustomerName',
    SUM('Sales_USD_2021') as 'Sales_USD_2021',
    SUM('Sales_USD_total') as 'Sales_USD_total',
    AVG(Field_max) as 'Field_avr'
FROM (
    SELECT
      t0.[CustomerID], t0.[Year]
      ,MAX(t0.[CustomerName]) as 'CustomerName'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN t0.[Year] = 2021 then t0.[SalesValue_USD] END) as 'Sales_USD_2021'
      ,SUM(t0.[SalesValue_USD]) as 'Sales_USD_total'
      ,MAX(t0.[Field])  as 'Field_max'
    From market t0
    Where [Year] in (2019,2020,2021)
    Group by t0.[CustomerID], t0.[Year] ) t
Group by [CustomerID]
```